# Freeze 1st, 3rd, 6th column in Telerik RadGrid control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a RadGrid property to Freeze columns by setting the count.
For ex if i set "FrozenColumnCount="1"" the first column of grid will be freezed. By increasing this count can set that many number of columns freeze.

But i want to do for Different columns like random  coulmns.

Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index of the column to do it like this :

```
myGridView.Columns[1].IsFrozen = true;
myGridView.Columns[3].IsFrozen = true;
myGridView.Columns[6].IsFrozen = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine how the UI behaviour would be when scrolling :)

But you can always first reorder the columns to make the desired columns be the first `n` ones and then set the `FronzenColumnCount` to `n`